# Left Outer Join in Criteria Api

Tags: java, left-join, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to get the following query using the Criteria API:

```
select lang.* from LKUP_LANG lang LEFT OUTER JOIN LANG_SEQUENCES seq ON
lang.SHORT_NAME=seq.LANG_CODE and (lang.DISPLAY_NAME is not null)
order by nvl(seq.SEQ_LANG_CODE, 2147483647) asc;
```

I did:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Lang> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Lang.class);
Root<Lang> languageRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Lang.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
// added some predicates
criteriaQuery.orderBy(...);
```

Tried adding

```
Join<Lang, LANG_SEQUENCES> join = languageRoot.join("languageSequences",JoinType.LEFT);
```

The entity looks like

```
LanguageSequences
@Id
@Column(name = "LANG_CODE")
private String langCode;

@Column(name = "SEQ_LANG_CODE")
private int seqLangcode;

@OneToOne
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "LANG_CODE", referencedColumnName = "SHORT_NAME")
private Lang lang;
```

and

```
Lang
@Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME", unique = true)
private String displayName;

@Id
@Column(name = "SHORT_NAME")
private String shortName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "lkupLanguage")
private LanguageSequences languageSequences;
```

Tried using joins in different ways but it looks like I'm missing something. I get the orderBy, the predicates all correct.
I'm using JPA 2.1 and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA you can not select a sequence, you should use native querys